# How to install firefox using the terminal app

Tags: macos, terminal, firefox

I am trying to install Mozila Firefox on the school's server via ssh. Given that I have authorization to install it on the server, could someone guide me through the steps to install firefox?

It has to be done through the Terminal, from my remote laptop using ssh instead of the graphical log in.

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming that you already have a connection via Terminal to the school server.

You need to download the .dmg first. Goto the directory in which you want to download the dmg file (command `cd \PATH\TO\DIR`)

Then enter this into the terminal:

```
curl http://mozilla.mirrors.tds.net/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/latest/mac/en-US/Firefox%2025.0.1.dmg -o firefox25.dmg
```

This is the latest Firefox Release for OS X.

Then mount the dmg:

```
hdiutil attach firefox25.dmg
```

Goto the mounted dmg (probably under Volumes):

```
cd /Volumes/Firefox
```

There you can find the `Firefox.app` which you can now copy to your Applications folder:

```
cp Firefox.app /Applications/Firefox.app
```

To unmount the dmg:

```
hdiutil detach /Volumes/Firefox
```